# ./gradlew signingReport from macos terminal

Tags: android-studio, gradle, gradlew

I'm trying to get a SHA1 certificate but I keep getting this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'signingReport' not found in root project 'juliapak' and its subprojects.

* Try:
> Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks.
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

I would like to be able to get my signing certificate from anywhere just by using mac terminal. My OS is ventura 13.4 How do I set up my .zshrc to do this?

Answer (score 0):

open terminal - navigate to root project folder -

```
cd android && ./gradlew app:signingReport
```